# Go to location after permission prompt on flutter_map_location_marker

Tags: flutter, fluttermap

I am using [flutter_map_location_marker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map_location_marker) to display the current user's location together with [flutter_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map).

I am [using the example given in the documentation](https://github.com/tlserver/flutter_map_location_marker/blob/master/example/lib/page/follow_fab_example.dart) that allows a user to click on a FAB (Floating Action Button) to follow the location.

I want the user to accept the location prompt, and the camera to be moved to the user location automatically.

This behavior already happens if the user has already accepted the location prompt and I change to a widget with the map. The problem lies when the user accepts the location prompt.